# Connect to WiFi Access Point programmatically with Android 10

Tags: android, android-wifi

With Android 10, I'm using the following method to connect to my Wifi Access Point :

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
public static void connectToWifiAccessPoint(String AP_SSID, String AP_PASSWORD, ConnectivityManager connectivityManager) {

    WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder builder = null;
    builder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder();

    builder.setSsid(AP_SSID);
    builder.setWpa2Passphrase(AP_PASSWORD);

    WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = builder.build();
    NetworkRequest.Builder networkRequestBuilder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
    networkRequestBuilder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
    networkRequestBuilder.setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier);
    NetworkRequest networkRequest = networkRequestBuilder.build();

    connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
                super.onAvailable(network);
                connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
            }
    });
}
```

A few seconds after calling this method, the OS displays this pop-up:

[image: Device to use with app]

After hitting the connect button, the same pop-up appears a few seconds later, and the
smartphone is still not connected to the access point.

Any idea how to fix this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggle couple days ago with wifi connection on Andrdoid Q, the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124728/connect-to-wifi-in-android-q-programmatically) of my question in stackOverflow.

So, the solution is **compile your app with targetSdkVersion 28.**
and for connection to wifi use this function :

```
 public void connectToWifi(String ssid, String key) {

    Log.e(TAG, "connection wifi pre Q");
    WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
    wifiConfig.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";
    wifiConfig.preSharedKey = "\"" + key + "\"";
    int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
    if (netId == -1) netId = getExistingNetworkId(wifiConfig.SSID);

    wifiManager.disconnect();
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
    wifiManager.reconnect();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution will be invalid soon: from November 2, 2020, a targetSdkVersion of at least 29 is required for app updates.

Comment: Yes I know, but Google developers should find a solution for that, this is just a workaround for the moment

Comment: Yes indeed. Here is the issue reported to Google : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138335744

Answer (score 0):

Try to forget the wifi Access point from saved networks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).