# Connect with Hidden network programatically in android 10

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-10.0

I am able to connect with hidden network for android 9 and lower versions using WifiConfigration API. But for android 10 and above there is different method introduced as `WifiNetworkSpecifier`. I tried connecting with hidden network by setting  `builder.setIsHiddenSsid(true);` but that seems does not worked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your code used on Android 10?

Comment: What device are you using for testing? I'm going through the same problem, but I do see the `WifiNetworkSpecifier` call work on Pixel devices ONLY. Maybe we can help each other figure this out?

Comment: hi @IvanGarza, I tried with samsung and MI devices but none of them worked well. I am not able to connect with hidden network for android 10 and above.

Comment: Makes sense. I mostly test with Pixel devices which always present me with the happy/ideal path.
Nevertheless, I tested a few Galaxy devices, Sony, and LGs and none of them work fine.
I've been searching for days regarding this issue, and I'm ready to conclude that the OEM's are simply not allowing this call to function correctly -- it wouldn't be the first time they fk something up, anyway.
Here's a good thread to look at with regards to that conclusion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124728/connect-to-wifi-in-android-q-programmatically/65327716#65327716