# Connect to a specific wifi programmatically in android using kotlin in android 10 and above

Tags: android, kotlin, wifi, android-wifi

I want to connect to a specific wifi in android programmatically using kotlin.

Till sdk level 28 we were using **WifiManager** api to connect to a specific wifi network programmatically, this is working fine for me.

But from sdk level 29 this way is deprecated and new way of wifi connection is introduced which is
**Wi-Fi suggestion API** to connect to a wifi with internet.

But I am not able to figure out how to connect to specific wifi network using this new **Wi-Fi suggestion API**

So please help me with it.

This it the code which I am using to connect to a specific wifi.

```
private fun connect(ssid: String, password:String): Int {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {

            val suggestion1: WifiNetworkSuggestion = WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
                .setSsid(ssid)
                .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
                .build()
            val suggestionsList: MutableList<WifiNetworkSuggestion> = ArrayList()
            suggestionsList.add(suggestion1)

            val wifiManager =
                applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
            val status = wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList)
            if (status == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "PSK network added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
//                Log.i(TAG, "PSK network added: $status")
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "PSK network not added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
//                Log.i(TAG, "PSK network not added: $status")
            }

            val specifier = WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                .setSsid(ssid)
                .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
                .build()

            val request = NetworkRequest.Builder()
                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED)
                .setNetworkSpecifier(specifier)
                .build()

            val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

            val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                    // do success processing here..
                    println("on available");
                }

                override fun onUnavailable() {
                    // do failure processing here..
                    println("on unavailable");
                }
            }
            connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request, networkCallback)

            return 123
        } else {
            val networkSSID = ssid
            val networkPass = password

            val conf = WifiConfiguration()
            conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\""

            conf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + networkPass + "\"";
            conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
            conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";
            val wifiManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
            wifiManager.addNetwork(conf)
            var list = listOf<WifiConfiguration>()
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            }
            else {
                list = wifiManager.configuredNetworks
            }
            for (i in list) {
                if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID == "\"" + networkSSID + "\"") {
                    wifiManager.disconnect()
                    wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true)
                    wifiManager.reconnect()
                    break
                }
            }
            return ssid.length
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the steps from here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65327716/8407336 as your question is a duplicate of it

Answer (score 0):

for connect wifi

```
 override fun connectWiFi(ssid: String, password: String) {
        beforeEnableWifiSelectedWifiName = selectedWifi.SSID
        beforeEnableWifiSelectedWifiPassword = password
        if (checkWifiStatus()) {
            when {
                Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q -> {
                    val wifiNetworkSpecifier: WifiNetworkSpecifier = if (password != "") {
                        WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                            .setSsid(beforeEnableWifiSelectedWifiName)
                            .setWpa2Passphrase(password)
                            .build()
                    } else {
                        WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                            .setSsid(beforeEnableWifiSelectedWifiName)
                            .build()
                    }


                    val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
                        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                        .setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier)
                        .build()

                    val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?

                    val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                            isHomeClick = false
                            super.onAvailable(network)
                            connectivityManager?.bindProcessToNetwork(network)
                        }


                        override fun onUnavailable() {
                            isHomeClick = false
                            super.onUnavailable()
                            showToast(getString(R.string.network_unavailable),true)
                        }

                        override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(network: Network, networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities) {
                            isHomeClick = false
                            savePasswordAndWifiNameInDatabase(ssid,
                                selectedWifi.BSSID,
                                password,
                                getSecurityType(selectedWifi))
                            showToast(getString(R.string.connected),true)
                            super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities)
                        }


                    }
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                        showDialogForOpenWifiSetting(this) {
                            connectivityManager?.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback)
                        }
                    } else {
                        connectivityManager?.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback)
                    }
                }
                else -> {
                    val wifiConfig = WifiConfiguration().apply {
                        SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", beforeEnableWifiSelectedWifiName)
                        preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", password)

                    }
                    with(wifiManager) {
                        val netId = addNetwork(wifiConfig)
                        disconnect()
                        enableNetwork(netId, true)
                        reconnect()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey savan, I tried your solution but with you solution wifi is disconnecting and connecting to the same wifi network again.

Comment: is it not woking in your case

Comment: no it is not working